# Opencart from MAMP to Web hosting

Tags: mysql, opencart, mamp, web-hosting

I have created an Opencart shop on my locally hosted site on MAMP. Now I have moved the site to a hosting company, I need to know what I need to update for the shop to work. I know that I need to edit the "config.php" files to point to the new links. Then upload the SQL db to the server.

I would be grateful for step by step instructions to get this to work. My opencart config files:

```
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://localhost:8888/shop/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'http://localhost:8888/shop/');

// DIR
define('DIR_APPLICATION', '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/shop/catalog/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/shop/system/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/shop/image/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/shop/catalog/language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/shop/catalog/view/theme/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/shop/system/config/');
define('DIR_CACHE', '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/shop/system/storage/cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/shop/system/storage/download/');
define('DIR_LOGS', '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/shop/system/storage/logs/');
define('DIR_MODIFICATION', '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/shop/system/storage/modification/');
define('DIR_UPLOAD', '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/shop/system/storage/upload/');

// DB
define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysqli');
define('DB_HOSTNAME', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'root');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'opencart');
define('DB_PORT', '3306');
define('DB_PREFIX', 'oc_');
```

I have contacted my hosting company and the address of folder is:

```
/home/cluster-sites/3/c/MYWEBSITE.co.uk/public_html/shop
```

What do I need to change?

My SQL db is set up on phpMyAdmin as "opencart". How do I transfer this to my hosting - do i need to keep naming exactly the same?

I have searched for a step by step guide but so far no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found a great step by step guide here:

https://www.squirrelhosting.co.uk/hosting-blog/hosting-blog-info.php?id=47

Is is now working for me